# mapping letters to pictures in Tkinter

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I am writing a program in Tkinter (and I am also using PIL),python, that is "translating" entered words on croatian to "Glgoljica". glagoljica is an old croatian alphabet that looks like this:

[image: croatian alphabet]

So I was wondering if there is a way to solve this with the dictionaries in Tkinter? For example can I map a letter "a" "with a picture of letter "a" on "glagoljica" ,letter b with pictures of letter "b" on glagoljica,so that as and end-result user gets a statement that is fully translated on that old croatian alphabet?

What I want is algorithm bellow ,but just with pics (instead of strings) as a values of `dict.keys()`.

```
dict={}
dict["a"]="e"
dict
>>>{'a': 'e'}
dict["i"]="u"
word="ai"
string=""
for letter in word:
    if letter in dict:
        string+=dict[letter]    
>>> string
'eu'
```

Comment: Do you have any code for rendering the Glgoljica alphabet?

Comment: How are you planning to output those letters? Do you want them to appear in a text field as you type, or to appear on a separate canvas after hitting some button?

Comment: Maybe you could just make a font.

Comment: Rebinding the builtin name `dict` is a very bad idea.

Comment: @jpp -> everything I've done so far I put in the new answer bellow.  I am new with Tkinter ,so any tips are welcome

Comment: @tobias_k on seperate canvas,after hitting "translate " button,I've put the code bellow

Answer (score 0):

The upper/lowercase glagoljica alphabet occupies unicode block U+2C00–U+2C5F, with U+2C2F and U+2C5F undefined.  Tkinter can handle and, depending on your system and the font you use, display the characters.  PIL should not be needed.

If you use a dict, it should map [slavic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode) chars to [glagoljica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode) chars.

```
glag = {'\u0410':'\u2C00', '\u0410':'\u2c01',}  # etc
print('\u0410', glag['\u0410'])
# ('А', 'Ⰱ')
```

I am using 3.4.2 on Win7 with Lucida Console.

However, instead of an explicit loop, string translation should use str.translate and a table from str.maketrans.

```
trans1 = str.maketrans(glag)
print('ААБАБ'.translate(trans1))
#'ⰁⰁБⰁБ'
```

With this, a dict object is not needed.

```
trans2 = str.maketrans('АБ', 'ⰁБ')  # could enter with \u excapes
print('ААБАБ'.translate(trans1))
#'ⰁⰁБⰁБ'
```

Comment: tnx,but I already know that they are inlucluded in unicode.
What I want is do it with pictures cuz I am new with Tkinter and I wanna play around a little bit.